# What is the maximum voltage permitted when MOC3061 is "on"?

Tags: opto-isolator

First, I am not an engineer,im a hobbyist.
I recently talked in a forum thread about (off-state output terminal voltage) in optocouplers.

A very good analogy was made between this off-state terminal voltage and Vce max of a BJT or Vds max of a MOS. Then I question about Voltage across MOC3061 optocuplor pins must not exceed 600V in the "off" state. Here is a direct link to this component if you feel is important: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/53872/FAIRCHILD/MOC3061/+_3JJ4UwYhRDpKxHeyUKwvhw+/datasheet.pdf

-Mister **NoiseEngineer** had give me a splendid answer about this problem i had. 
I summarized what i understood from him here, and also i come with an additional question still related to this case: -When the junction is closed (not current activated), its practically a big resistance in circuit, that supports maximum up to 600V in this case to not get damaged. But what if the junction is "on"(it's Gate/Base is open) and the same 600V are applied? Is the same thing as when is in "off" mode? It's the resistivity of the metals + some conductivity in play? Then i should ask, what is the maximum voltage permitted when is "on" ? Still 600V maxim (in this case) or greater(because of conductivity)?

--Thank you--

Comment: If it's 600V when it's on, what would the current be? Something far higher than its current rating, i'm sure.

Comment: No. Im asking about the voltage, not current.

Comment: Voltage and current are not independent.

Comment: Specific for this component, its Current forward (If) = 60mA.

Comment: Im a bit too specific with my question right now, but im also open for general explanation, like the comparison made with the Vce max of a BJT or Vds max of a MOS.

Comment: The on state of a switch is defined as having the lowest possible voltage across it and the highest possible current through it. You can think of it as setting the resistance as low as possible; this is in fact what the Rds,on specification for a FET is. If your switch is on, and yet still has 60 V across it, the current is going to be extremely high, in all likelihood high enough to completely destroy the switch.

Comment: "The on state of a switch is defined as having the lowest possible voltage across it and the highest possible current through it."
This is very interesting and  new for me, thank you. And also Rds explanation, i like it. 
 I understand your point now, so basically, they omit this information in the datasheet. It should be an open state voltage specification. Im my mind, i imagine the on state is permitting way more voltage than in off state, simply because of the conductivity, so they didnt bothered to tell this, only the criticalpart, meaning, when is off and is resisting to a max V.

Comment: (specifically for this component)
But your explanation is more general and i like it.
For this, you really deserve a thumb up.

Comment: I kind of getting now, from your good answer.
Thank you !
You can make it oficial and I'll give you the Ok, but in the same time im also curious what others may say.

Comment: "*Specific for this component, its Current forward (If) = 60mA.*" Do you realise that is the maximum forward current **for the infrared LED**, not the triac?

Comment: @Transistor       I really believe it to be as well, but its the device Emitter current 60mA. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/gWzis89
It is also specified, down in the file, the current for the LED too. But we must look more careful for it because its in the end of the line. 
Here https://imgur.com/kVePEEA   is the led specs screenshot:

Comment: **The emitter *is* the LED.** It emits infrared light. It is guaranteed to turn on the triac when the LED current is 10 mA. The LED can take 60 mA maximum. The triac can pass 1 A. These are **absolute max** ratings and not where you want to operate.

Comment: If this is the line you are looking at when you are mentioning that 1A: https://imgur.com/A4LiUir
then mister *le_top* already provided a very competent answer about this problem,in one of the answers.  I'll reference his explanation about this specific thing:  " However, 120 pulses of 100uS @1A are allowed in 1 second, which would be a total ontime of 12ms in one second. In that case, the component would consume about 0.012s.1A.5V=60mW. The device can dissipate the 60mW." And I am very much agree with his explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The on state of a switch can be (loosely) defined as having the lowest possible voltage across it and the highest possible current through it. You can think of it as setting the resistance as low as possible; this is in fact what the \$R_{ds,on}\$ specification for a FET is. If your switch is on, and yet still has 60 V across it, the current is going to be extremely high, in all likelihood high enough to completely destroy the switch.

Consider a typical power MOSFET with an \$R_{ds,on}\$ of, say, 10 mΩ. If you have 60 V across it, Ohm's law tells you that the current is \$\frac{60\ \mathrm{V}}{10\ \mathrm{mΩ}} = 6\ \mathrm{kA}\$. I don't know about you, but I've certainly never seen a FET that can handle six thousand amperes through it. And even then, the static power dissipation will be \$P = (6\ \mathrm{kA})^2 · 10\ \mathrm{mΩ} = 360\ \mathrm{kW}\$, which is a completely absurd amount of power to have to dissipate; your FET is likely to be vaporized.

The problem actually gets even worse with devices like your optocoupler, which is based on a triac. Triacs have a diode-like V/I curve, which means the relationship between current and voltage is not linear like a resistor or on-state FET, but *exponential*.

Regarding your comment:

> Im my mind, i imagine the on state is permitting way more voltage than in off state, simply because of the conductivity, so they didnt bothered to tell this [...]

In actuality, the on state permits way less voltage than the off state, as described above. The on state voltage is limited by the maximum on-state current, which the datasheet *will* tell you. In some cases, they may also give you a minimum on state voltage, particularly in BJTs, IGBTs, diodes, diacs, triacs, and similar devices (including optocouplers based on any of those). In the case of a BJT or IGBT, this will be called \$V_{CE, sat}\$, the saturation voltage, and in the case of a diode it will be called the forward voltage. These are voltages below which the device can't be considered "fully on"; they won't allow as much current through as when they're fully on.

Comment: ___Thank you___

Answer (score 1):

> When the junction is closed (not current activated), its practically a big resistance in circuit,

No, we call that an open-circuit. It comes from the days of switch contacts. Switch open = contacts separated = no conduction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxt0us.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Open and closed switches.*

> ... that supports maximum up to 600 V in this case to not get damaged.

In the off-state (open-circuit) the device's triac can withstand 600 V.

> But what if the junction is "on" (it's Gate/Base is open) and the same 600 V are applied?

The device you have referenced contains a triac. It doesn't have a base.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd3o6L.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) Incorrect application. (b) Correct application.*

You never apply 600 V to a triac (or any other switch) without some form of current limiting. In Figure 1a the fuse would blow when D1 is turned on - if the triac doesn't blow first. In Figure 1b the lamp will limit the current to a safe value and the voltage across TRI1 will fall to about 1 V AC. The high voltage will be dropped across the lamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5SJ1X.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. An equivalent circuit for Figure 2. When the switches are open, as shown, the full voltage appears across the switch. If you close SW2 the voltage across the switch falls to zero. If you close SW1 you may see some voltage across the switch because of the huge current flowing through the contact resistance.*

> Is the same thing as when is in "off" mode? It's the resistivity of the metals + some conductivity in play?

No. Triacs are made of semiconductor material - silicon.

> Then I should ask, what is the maximum voltage permitted when is "on"? Still 600 V maxim (in this case) or greater (because of conductivity)?

As explained, the voltage when on is only about 1 V or so. You will find the value in the datasheet.

You may wish to revisit your previous question. I don't think you understood any of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The output voltage over the MOS is a pretty strict relation with the current.  A typical graph is given as the first graph in the datasheet ($V_TM$, ON–STATE VOLTAGE (VOLTS) ).

The graph is specified only from -800mA to +800mA.  That is because the device can only dissipate 250mW at 25°C and less at higher temperatures.  According to the datasheet you need lower that value of 250mW by 1.41 mW/°C.

This maximum power dissipation is the most limiting factor.
Suppose that the current is 0.8A, then the voltage is about 4V, so the consumption would be 3.2W which is already too high for the package in continuous mode.  However, 120 pulses of 100uS @1A are allowed in 1 second, which would be a total ontime of 12ms in one second.  In that case, the component would consume about \$0.012 s . 1A . 5V = 60mW\$.  The device can dissipate the 60mW.

The \$$I_f\$$ current mentionned in one of the comments is only the maximum current that could be consumed by the input LED.  The actual current depends on the external resistance and to make sure that the device is on, the current needs to be between the minimum on current and the maximum current.  Lower is better for power consumption.

The forward voltage is specified for 30mA only, the maximum voltage is then 1.5V for the input LED.  The consumption would be 45mW.  You can see that this is quite a bit compared to the 60mW that we computed for the output.

The power that the device must disspate, is the sum of the LED power and the output switch power.

Suppose that we have the above operating conditions - the total power that the MOS would need to dissipate is 105mW.  The maximum operating temperature is then \$25°C + (250mW-105mW)/(1.41mW/°C) = 102°C\$ which is higher thant the specified temperature, so it can operate at maximum 85°C.  In fact, at 85°C you can dissipate \$250mW-(85°C-25°C) . 1.41mW/°C=191mW\$

So, the voltage on the output will depend on the output current.

Within allowed operating conditions it has to be between -5V and +5V.  Beyond these limits you should expect your device to break.

The "exact" voltage can determined from graph I referenced above - it will of course vary with the instantaneous current - the rms voltage will depend on that current profile and related voltage profile.